# Как вызывать функцию в классе, которая описана в main?

Tags: java, ооп

Есть простая собственная функция преобразования числа в строку. Ее надо использовать и в классе, и в `main ()`.

Если описать ее в `main ()` то в классе ее не видно. Если описать в классе, то придется в `main ()` вызывать ее обращаясь к классу. Так и сделаю если узнаю что нет нет других вариантов. По логике она не очень то в классе и нужна. Если есть способ вызова из `main ()` то подскажите.

Я описываю ее в `main ()` так:

```
static string func()
{//
}
```

Comment: Нашел способ такой - в классе вызвать функцию через название класса в котором содержится main.

Comment: как сделать [mcve] .... ну и саму проблему стоит нормально описать, а не потоком сознания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `main()` - это метод, то в методах в джаве нельзя создавать другие методы.
Но, очевидно, Вы имели в виду, "главный" класс (содержащий метод `main()`).
Итак, в "главном" классе Вы объявили `func()` с уровнем доступа package. Так что все должно быть видно в пределах пакета.

Как Вы пытаетесь "увидеть" ваш метод из другого класса?

Вообще, подобные методы реализуют в отдельном классе (называют его типа `StringUtil`), и как правило, они статические. (Как пример, посмотрите на класс `Math`).

Comment: В главном классе я объявил func(). В package есть еще пара классов со своими методами и полями. Например есть класс Interval. Внутри него не получается просто обратиться к func(). Из-за двух функции стоит ли создавать отдельный класс?  Хороший вариант.

Comment: Почему не получается? Можно глянуть? В любом методе пишете Main.func();

Comment: я писал просто func(). Спасибо.

Comment: Можно и так, но тогда используйте статический импорт класса, в котором описана ваша func()